How can I set rotation origin point without using an empty to pivot around?
I am animating a character in rigify. The character moves in a straight line, and then around a circle. A bit like the shape of a question mark. I want the movement around the circular portion to be very smooth.
I am animating the root bone of a rigify rig. I can sort of get it to work by using . > Pivot Point > 3D Cursor. It then looks good when I rotate the root bone in the viewport, but when I add keyframes, the interpolation is wrong.
I've noticed the problem also happens when trying to move a simple cube around a circle so I've recorded a demo of this minimal example. How can I ensure the keyframes use the pivot point correctly so the cube moves correctly around the circle?
Most places suggest using an empty as a parent, and then rotating around the empty. However, this would not work for the real world use-case, as its a rigify root bone, and I only want it to move around a pivot point for part of the animation.
Is there a way to get the rotation keyframes to respect the pivot point?
Demo: https://ibb.co/31dD9XK

The Transform Pivot Point is a helpful editing guide, it is not used for keyframing or anything, keyframes are always using the object's frame of reference, i.e. either world coordinates or the parent coordinates if the object is a child of another object. Like location, rotation and scale values in the sidepanel, which are never in relation to the pivot point, but the frame of reference (unless pivot point and transform orientation are matching the frame of reference). That's not a "problem" that happens, it's how it works. Otherwise each change of the pivot point would mess up animations.

Why not use the "Follow Path" constraint?

Be sure to click the Animate Path button.   Enable Follow Curve if you want the object to turn to match the curvature of the path at any point.  Also, there are ways to make the object "tilt" into the curve, as if your character were leaning into a curve.  Look this constraint up: there are ways to animate when to follow the curve, whether to go beyond the cure, animate the influence (when to lock onto the curve), how many frame to traverse the cure, and so on.   I used a question-mark type curve for you!


I had to fiddle with the axes and root bone position a bit, but with its influence feature, it worked great for this use case. Great suggestion!
